# Ubuntu is booting too slowly

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive

I recently switched from Kali/Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04.

Specs:

- CPU: Intel i5 7200U
- RAM: 8GB
- GPU: Nvidia 940mx and a dedicated Intel GPU
- HDD: 1TB

With the above specs I get a 1 minute 15 second boot time and after I login with my password it takes another 15 seconds. Is this normal with a HDD? Should I buy an SSD or is there something wrong?

```
 4:06:03 PM gnome-logs: gtk_style_context_remove_class: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_CONTEXT (context)' failed
 4:04:11 PM systemd: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
 4:04:11 PM dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1348] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
 4:04:10 PM systemd: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
 4:04:10 PM dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1348] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.25' (uid=1000 pid=1492 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
 4:03:36 PM packagekitd: resolve transaction /186_dcebceda from uid 1000 finished with success after 581ms
 4:03:24 PM systemd: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
 4:03:24 PM dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1348] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
 4:03:24 PM gnome-shell: Object Clutter.Clone (0x55a5642d7bf0), has been already deallocated - impossible to access to it. This might be caused by the fact that the object has been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs
 4:03:24 PM systemd: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
 4:03:24 PM dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1348] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.25' (uid=1000 pid=1492 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
 4:03:09 PM systemd: Started Hostname Service.
 4:03:09 PM dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
 4:03:08 PM systemd: Starting Hostname Service...
 4:03:08 PM dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.118' (uid=1000 pid=2891 comm="gnome-control-center -s system " label="unconfined")
 4:03:01 PM packagekitd: resolve transaction /185_eaebeaba from uid 1000 finished with success after 530ms
 4:02:58 PM gdm-x-session: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  141.40  1920 1968 2000 2142  1080 1083 1089 1100 +hsync -vsync (66.0 kHz eP)
 4:02:51 PM systemd: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
 4:02:51 PM dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1348] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
 4:02:51 PM systemd: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
 4:02:51 PM dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1348] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.25' (uid=1000 pid=1492 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
 4:02:17 PM gnome-logs: gtk_style_context_add_class: assertion 'GTK_IS_STYLE_CONTEXT (context)' failed
 4:01:49 PM wpa_supplicant: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-53 noise=9999 txrate=58500
 4:01:48 PM gnome-logs: Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.avail/53-monospace-lcd-filter.conf", line 10: Having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected
 4:01:47 PM packagekitd: resolve transaction /184_babaddec from uid 1000 finished with success after 416ms
 4:01:45 PM snap-confine: main.go:192: cannot change mount namespace of snap "gnome-logs" according to change mount (/snap/gtk-common-themes/818/share/icons/Suru /snap/gnome-logs/45/data-dir/icons/Suru none bind,ro 0 0): cannot use "/snap/gtk-common-themes/818/share/icons/Suru" as bind-mount source: not a directory
 4:01:43 PM dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1348] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Calendar'
 4:01:43 PM systemd: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
 4:01:43 PM dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1348] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
 4:01:43 PM systemd: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
 4:01:43 PM dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1348] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.25' (uid=1000 pid=1492 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
 3:57:52 PM systemd: Started Message of the Day.
 3:55:31 PM gnome-shell: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.86/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/software_update_available
 3:55:25 PM packagekitd: get-details transaction /183_dedabdab from uid 1000 finished with success after 837ms
 3:55:14 PM gnome-software: Unable to acquire bus name 'org.gnome.Software'
 3:55:03 PM rsyslogd: main Q:Reg: worker thread 55a97da74de0 terminated, now 1 active worker threads [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2439 ]
 3:55:02 PM systemd: Started BAMF Application Matcher Framework.
 3:55:02 PM dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1348] Successfully activated service 'org.ayatana.bamf'
 3:55:01 PM systemd: Starting BAMF Application Matcher Framework...
 3:55:00 PM dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1348] Activating via systemd: service name='org.ayatana.bamf' unit='bamfdaemon.service' requested by ':1.82' (uid=1000 pid=2035 comm="plank " label="unconfined")
 3:54:59 PM systemd: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
 3:54:59 PM dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1348] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
 3:54:59 PM systemd: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
 3:54:59 PM dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=1348] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.25' (uid=1000 pid=1492 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
 3:54:59 PM gnome-shell: Object Clutter.Clone (0x55a5642d71d0), has been already deallocated - impossible to access to it. This might be caused by the fact that the object has been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs
 3:54:44 PM packagekitd: resolve transaction /170_eaaeaeaa from uid 1000 finished with success after 700ms
 3:54:43 PM gnome-software: Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
 3:54:43 PM packagekitd: get-updates transaction /169_bbbcadad from uid 1000 finished with success after 557ms
 3:54:41 PM systemd: Started Firmware update daemon.
 3:54:41 PM dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd'
 3:54:40 PM fwupd: Daemon ready for requests
```

```
systemd-analyze blame
         26.084s systemd-journal-flush.service
         21.290s dev-sda2.device
         18.962s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         11.013s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
         10.526s plymouth-start.service
          9.068s systemd-udevd.service
          8.571s networkd-dispatcher.service
          7.261s dev-loop9.device
          7.045s dev-loop8.device
          6.686s udisks2.service
          6.508s dev-loop4.device
          6.466s dev-loop5.device
          6.437s dev-loop6.device
          6.409s dev-loop7.device
          6.246s grub-common.service
          6.145s dev-loop0.device
          6.040s dev-loop3.device
          5.616s dev-loop1.device
          5.609s dev-loop2.device
          5.597s snapd.service
          5.241s ModemManager.service
          5.206s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-45.mount
          5.078s bolt.service
```

Comment: Hello Survival, how did you do that? Thank you for the edit.)

Comment: Take a tour of [Editing Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help) ;-)

Comment: if you don't mind design and have some time, than give Lubuntu a try. HDD is always slow. My old intel celeron dual core from my 10 year old dell inspirion 6400 laptop boots into less than 30 seconds into lubuntu 16.04 and opens up my browser. SSD droped in price by almost 50% respecting to their pricing one year ago. I would install one in any case.

Comment: Hello @AlexOnLinux, do you think that it's normal? 1.15 sec is too much IMO for a i5 7th gen processor...

Comment: It looks like the major culprit is systemd-journal-flush.service. You can try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139513/how-to-clear-journalctl

Comment: Now, it's like this. We have saved 17 sec! Thanks guys.
<pre>17.973s dev-sda2.device
         15.723s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          9.181s systemd-journal-flush.service
          8.400s plymouth-start.service
          8.220s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          8.002s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          7.845s networkd-dispatcher.service
          6.581s systemd-sysctl.service
          6.116s bolt.service
          5.809s udisks2.service
          5.670s snapd.service
          5.089s ModemManager.service
          5.066s dev-loop9.device
       
</pre>

Comment: 4.835s NetworkManager.service
          4.533s dev-loop8.device
          4.258s dev-loop4.device
          4.195s dev-loop7.device
          4.113s dev-loop6.device
          3.929s fwupd.service
          3.886s dev-loop0.device
          3.768s dev-loop3.device
          3.763s dev-loop1.device
          3.711s grub-common.service

Answer (score 2):

you can this command

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

this command prints a list of all running units, ordered by the time they took to initialize. This information used to optimize boot-up times.

find which service take more time and is not necessary
you can use

`systemctl disable <service-name>`

to remove service from startup.

Comment: I added the result to the topic. Are any of them unnecessary?